# Why ZeroMQ PUB/SUB example in python does not receive any messages?

Tags: python, zeromq

I was trying to run ZeroMQ `PUB/SUB`-archetype example in python ([wuserver](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:wuserver), [wuclient](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:wuclient)) from the guide and it does not work for me.

I tried it on an Ubuntu VM. I am running `python3.6.1` with `pyzmq.__version__ == 16.0.3` on `ubuntu 16.10` (in VM). If I change sockets' archetypes from `PUB/SUB` to `PUSH/PULL`, the client starts getting messages, as expected.

- What am I missing?
- And what can I do to find out the cause of this unexpected behavior?

I start a `SUB`-client before the `PUB`-server (I've tried the other way around too) but `SUB` never gets any message.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior.  I just tried exactly that using python 3.6.2 (with pyzmq 16.0.3) and the code straight from the links you provided, and it works without a problem.

Comment: I assumed that the examples must work. What I am missing is how to figure out what is wrong with my setup. Given that pull/push works, what can prevent sub/pub to work?

Comment: I know that ubuntu 16.10 has python 3.5.2.  Where are you getting 3.6.1 from? I wonder if I can try to replicate your environment.

Answer (score 2):

The example was actually working out of the box. I commented out `socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, zip_filter)` instead of providing an empty string for `zip_filter` and that did not allow anything to be received by the socket. I failed to perceive the importance of `setsockopt_string` call.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: This is **exactly the reason, why StackOverflow insists on presenting an MCVE-formulated code.** You have mis-directed other Community Memebers, who sponsored the problem-finding process, as you have **(a)** stated "*I assumed that the examples must work*", which only weakly referred to an externally published generic code, **but** you have **(b)** confirmed "*I commented out*..." parts of the code, which has principally changed the nature of the code-execution. This is not an acceptable practice. **Next, post only a fully-elaborated MCVE-code, if asking StackOverflow Members to help**, ok?

Answer (score 0):

### Let's start with the 2<sup>nd</sup> question: Sorry, this IS *expected behaviour*

ZeroMQ archetypes were defined so as to represent a certain behaviour. As said, `PUSH`-archetype AccessPoint pushes every message "through" all the so far setup communication channels, `PULL`-er AccessPoint pulls anything that has arrived down the line(s) to "it's hands", `PUB`-lisher AccessPoint publishes, `SUB`-scriber AccessPoint subscribes, so as to receive just the messages, that match it's topic-filter(s), but not any other.

As it seems clear, such Archetype "specification" helps build the ZeroMQ smart messaging / signaling infrastructure for our ease of use in [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) architectures.

### Why it did not deliver a single message? Simply, it MUST NOT deliver.

As defined, a just instantiated **`SUB`**-side AccessPoint object has literally zero-chance to know, what will be the choice of what messages are those right ones, so that they ought be "delivered" and what messages are not.

Without this initial piece of knowledge, ZeroMQ designers had a principal choice to **be either** Archetype-policy consistent and let `PUB`-side AccessNode to distribute all the `.send()`-acquired messages only to those `SUB`-side AccessNode(s), that have explicitly requested to receive any such, right via the `zmq.SUBSCRIBE`-mechanics **or** to deliver everything sent from `PUB` also to all so far un-decided `SUB`-s.

The former was a consistent and professional design step from ZeroMQ authors.
The latter would actually mean to violate ZeroMQ own RFC-specification.

The latter choice would be something like if one has just moved to a new apartment, one would hardly expect to find all newspapers and magazines to appear delivered in one's new mailbox from next morning on, would one? But if one subscribes to Boston Globe, the very next morning the fresh release will be at the doorstep as it will remain to be there, until one cancels the subscription or the newspaper went bankrupt or a lack of paper rolls prevented the printing shop from delivering in due time and fashion or a traffic jam in the Big Dig tunnel might have caused troubles for all or just the local delivery some one particular day.

All this is natural and compatible with the Archetype-policy.

<sub>*Intermezzo:*

Technology purists will object here, that early API releases ( till some v3.2+ ) actually did technically transport all message-payloads from a `PUB` to all `SUB`-s, as it simplified `PUB`-side workload envelope, but increased transport-class(es) data-flow and `SUB`-side resources / deferred topic-filter processing. Yet all this was hidden from user-code, right by the API horizon of abstraction. So, except of a need to properly scale resources, this was transparent to user. More recent API versions reverted the role of topic-filter processor and let this to now happen on the `PUB`-side. Nevertheless, in both cases, the ZeroMQ RFC specification policy is implemented in such a manner, the `SUB`-side will never deliver ( through the `.recv()`-interface ) a single message, that was not matching the valid, explicit `SUB`-side subscription(s)</sub>

In all cases a `SUB`-side has not yet explicitly set any `zmq.SUBSCRIBE`-instructed topic-filter, **it cannot and will not deliver anything** ( which is both natural and fully-consistent with the ZeroMQ RFC Archetype-policy defined for the `SUB`-type AccessPoint ).

### Answer to the 1<sup>st</sup> question: The Best Next Step:

Always, at least, read the ZeroMQ API documentation, where all details are professionally specified - so at least, one can get a first glimpse on the breath of the smart messaging / signalling framework.

This will not help anyone to start on a green-field and fully-build one's own  complex mental-concept and indepth understanding of how all the things work internally, which is obviously not any API-documentation's ambition, is it? Yet, this will help anyone to refresh or remind about all configurable details, once one has mastered the ZeroMQ internal architecture, as detailed in the source, referred in the next paragraph.

Plus, for anyone, who is indeed interested in [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) or just [zeromq](/questions/tagged/zeromq) per-se, it is worth one's time and efforts to always read Pieter HINTJENS' book "Code Connected, Volume 1" ( freely available in pdf ) plus any other of his books on his rich experience on software engineering later, because his many insights into modern computing may and will inspire ( and lot ).